# Django cannot cast type integer to smallint when attempting to filter a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, filtering, django-queryset

I have an `IntegerChoices` `Genre`:

```
from django.db import models
# ...

class Genre(models.IntegerChoices):
    fantasy = 0,
    scifi = 1,
    real = 2,
    #...
```

and a `book` model that uses an `ArrayField` of `PositiveSmallIntegerField` with `Genre` as choices:

```
from django.contrib.postgre.fields import ArrayField
#...

class Book(models.Model):
    #...
    genres = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Genre.choices), null=True, blank=True))
    #...
```

When I try to filter by the `genres` field using values from the `Genre` choices I get an error that Django (or psycopg2) cannot cast an integer to a smallint:

```
# traceback
psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type integer to smallint[]
LINE 1: ..."book" WHERE "book"."genres" @> 1::smallint...
                                            ^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
# traceback
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to smallint[]
LINE 1: ..."book" WHERE "book"."genres" @> 1::smallint...
                                            ^
```

All of these attempts to filter trigger the above error:

```
genre = Genre.scifi
print(genre) # >>> 1
Book.objects.filter(genres__contains=genre) # error
Book.objects.filter(genres=genre) # error
```

However if I try to create a `book` instance with the genre everything works.

```
book = Book.objects.create(
    #...
    genres=[genre]
) # no error
print(book.genres) # >>> [1]
```

Is the problem the `PositiveSmallIntegerField`? I couldn't find any "SmallIntegerChoices" as a replacement for the `IntegerChoices`.
Or is it the way the filtering is/should be done? I haven't had this issue before and by searching I haven't found anything that looks the same (some errors with migrations or other type casting, but nothing quite like this).
It does feel like a simple problem, but I can't find my way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are querying the ArrayField, you need to provide an array of value(s), you can not simply pass the value itself, so in this case, the variable 'genre' you are passing should be an array of value like, [1] or [1, 2, 3] for multiple values. It should fix your problem.

Documentation of Querying in [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield) for reference.

Comment: I thought it was something simple. Can't really say why an error isn't thrown earlier or something instead of this rather confusing typecast mention, but this worked splendidly.
`Book.objects.filter(genres__contains=[genre])`